# Nuxt many processes running when running dev server

Tags: docker, express, nuxt.js

Here is the output of htop command.

[image]

As you can see, `/usr/local/bin/node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js` is running on many processes.

Is this a normal behavior of dev server or is something wrong?

Details on my development:
Nuxt(using express as server) + typescript with docker-compose.
Source code is on docker named volume and editing it from vscode by remote container.

I run the server by this command `node node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js` by `yarn dev`.

Note:
After stopping yarn dev command with ctrl-c, those processes are still running.

I restarted docker containers by docker-compose restart and those processes weren't there but after running the server, they appeared again.

Answer (score 0):

This was because in my cli the dev server processes weren't killed by ctrl+C.
That's why so many processes were alive.